# Logstash, multiple instances with redis pub/sub input. Should I expect duplicates?

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash, publish-subscribe

I have a working ELK pipeline, with a redis input and elasticsearch output, with a single logstash instance.

In order to make it more reliable I'd like to scale it up to 2 instances and use a load balancer in front of them.

I am worried about getting duplicated data.
In fact, the pub/sub mechanism should post the data to both logstash receivers, and I see no reason why I shouldn't get duplicated documents on ES.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

edit.

This is the logstash input config:

```
input {
  redis {
    add_field => {
      type => "xml_request_log"
    }
    data_type => "channel"
    key => "xml_requests_log"
    batch_count => "100"
    host => "my.redis.host"
  }
}
```

I don't think the output (elasticsearch) and filter parts are relevant for my question